# How to marshal a pointer to fixed size array in c#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a C++ DLL with an exported function:

```
__declspec (dllexport) int AllocateBuf(DataBufferIn *in);
```

This function allocate buffer array and assign value for test

```
__declspec (dllexport) int AllocateBuf(DataBufferIn *in){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++){
        in->data_r[i] = (double*)VirtualAlloc(
            NULL,                 // System selects address
            1024 * sizeof(double), // Size of allocation
            MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, // Allocate reserved pages
            PAGE_READWRITE);       // Protection = no access
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; i++){
            (in->data_r[i])[j] = j;//Assign value for test    
        }
    }

}
```

The struct DataBufferIn  is like this

```
struct DataBufferIn
{
    double* data_r[4];
    double* data_g[4];
};
```

The following is my code, i wanna marshal this struct in c#, but I get a exception `(An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException' occurred in C_Sharp_Sample.exe)`. I get stuck in this for much times, does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks :)

```
public struct DataBufferIn
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public IntPtr[] data_r;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public IntPtr[] data_g;
};

[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int AllocateBuf(ref DataBufferIn _data_buf_in);

private void button_allocate_buf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBufferIn data_buf_in = new DataBufferIn();
    AllocateBuf(ref data_buf_in);//<---Function call fail...

    double[] doubleArrayRed = new double[1024];
    Marshal.Copy(data_buf_in.lum_data_r[0], doubleArrayRed, 0, 1024);
    .....
}
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up: the only arrays you are passing have `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` so how do you get `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException` (which indicates you are passing an array as a `SAFEARRAY` somehow)? Perhaps also add `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` to your struct definition

Comment: @Charlieface Your correct, The sequential should add, Thanks for your help:)

Comment: If you're happy, answer yourself and close this question

Answer (score -1):

According to Charlieface suggestion,
Add [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] could solve this issue.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DataBufferIn
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public IntPtr[] data_r;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public IntPtr[] data_g;
};
```